# Create my own Dll for my C# App

Tags: c#

Hi how to create my own dll for my c# application.

Comment: can you add more context about what you have at the moment? Any library project will build to a dll...

Comment: Way too vague to be given a meaningful answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Visual Studio:

1. open Solution Explorer
2. right mouse click on solution
3. Add | New Project
4. Pick Class Library

To use it in other projects you must add reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio -> New Project -> Class Library
And after compile you will have .dll in bin/debug directory

Comment: So a .dll is nothing but a pre compiled class?

Comment: @Gunner: It's a compiled assembly consisting of one or more classes.

Comment: Tu use it, you have to reference it in your application by clicking right mouse button on "References" and selecting your .dll, you can also set  "copy to program directory", so you wont have to copy it manualy.

Answer (score 1):

Create a New Project with the template > ClassLibrary, then add classes into it and build the project. Now your dll will be copied to the \bin\debug folder. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new Project, select "Class Library", this will compile to a dll.

For an existing project, on the project properties, on the application tab, for "Output Type" select "Class Library".

If you have a Windows App, and you want to expose some of it's functionality as a DLL, then you need to factor out the functionality to a seperate class library project.